# Angular ui-bootstrap tabs not rendering ui-view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

I am upgrading an existing angular app to all the latest versions of angular (v1.2.13), ui-router (v0.2.8), and ui-bootstrap (v0.10.0).

I have nested views that have multiple named views. One of the named views has tabs inside of it.  I used to be able to set `ui-views` within each tab, but that no longer is working.  If I don't use the tabs then the named views render correctly.

I have created a [plunkr to show what I'm seeing.](http://plnkr.co/edit/cw6O6mX7frZqKJEeGC9Y?p=preview)

Here is my state configuraiton. `_split.html` has 3 named views: `TOP`, `MIDDLE`, and `BOTTOM`.  `TOP` and `MIDDLE` both have named views `LEFT` and `RIGHT`.  `TOP` has tabs and does not render the views `LEFT` or `RIGHT`. `MIDDLE` has the same named views and they render correctly.

```
  $stateProvider
      .state("foo", {
        abstract: true,
          url: "/foo",
          templateUrl: '_split.html',
      })
      .state("foo.view", {
        abstract: true,
        url: '',
        views: {
          'TOP': {
            template: '_tabs.html'
          },
          'MIDDLE': {
             templateUrl: '_tabs2.html'
          },
          'BOTTOM': {
            template: '<h2>Bottom</h2>'
          }
        },
      })
      .state("foo.view.tabs", {
        url: '',
        views: {
          'LEFT': {
            template: '<h3>Left</h3>'
          },
          'RIGHT': {
            template: '<h3>Right</h3>'
          }
        }
      })
```

**Is there any way to render ui-view within tabs?**

Comment: It works good with v0.2.7 (ui-router). I have this problem only with v0.2.8. Maybe it's a bug?

Comment: Confirmed: Something has changed between v0.2.7 and v0.2.8 to break this. In my case, rolling back to v0.2.7 resolved the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, you can render ui-views within tabs. The trick is to use `ui-sref` in `<tab-heading>` to control the state/route change, and have the `ui-view` below the `</tabset>`. I'm sure there are other ways, but thats how I got tabs working with ui-router.

> **edit update**

Above original suggestion is wrong, `ui-sref` should be in `<tab>`

Hat tip to [chris-t](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3225368/chris-t) for correct config.

Working multiple views demo http://plnkr.co/edit/gXnFS3?p=preview

index.html

```
<tabset>
  <tab ui-sref="left">
    <tab-heading style="cursor:pointer;">
      <a ui-sref-active="active">Left</a>
    </tab-heading>
  </tab>
  <tab ui-sref="right">
    <tab-heading style="cursor:pointer;">
      <a ui-sref-active="active">Right</a>
    </tab-heading>
  </tab>
</tabset>
<div class="row">
  <br>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="well" ui-view="viewA">
      <!--Here is the A content-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="well" ui-view="viewB">
      <!--Here is the B content-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.js (ui-router config)

```
$stateProvider
.state('left', {
  url: "/",
  views: {
    "viewA": {
      template: "Left Tab, index.viewA"
    },
    "viewB": {
      template: 'Left Tab, index.viewB<br><a ui-sref=".list">Show List</a>' +
                '<div ui-view="viewB.list"></div>'
    },
    "viewC": {
      template: 'Left Tab, index.viewC <div ui-view="viewC.list"></div>'
    }
  }
})
.state('left.list', {
  url: 'list',
  views: {
    "viewB.list": {
      template: '<h2>Nest list viewB</h2><ul>' +
                '<li ng-repeat="thing in tab1things">{{thing}}</li></ul>',
      controller: 'Tab1ViewBCtrl',
      data: {}
    },
    "viewC.list": {
      template: 'Left Tab, list.viewC'
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I was able to get a working version using this method so thanks. I previously was able to have both tabs already loaded so that switching between them was basically instant. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yeah, have a look @ how https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp build system works, .html templates are injected into the DOM on app load, compiled by grunt. From the README.md: delta:tpls - When any *.tpl.html file within src/ changes, all templates are put into strings in a JavaScript file (technically two, one for src/common/ and another for src/app/) that will add the template to AngularJS's $templateCache so template files are part of the initial JavaScript payload and do not require any future XHR. The template cache files are build/template-app.js and build/template-common.js.

Comment: @cheekybastard Is it that you have to click on the link inside the tab header ? In my case, clicking on the square tab header changes the current tab but does not click on the link and therefore does not change the state.

Comment: Yes its a link driving the state change. The link contains a ui-router directive `ui-sref` with the ui-router state to call. You can use `ng-click` to call state change by clicking anywhere on tab header.

Comment: @cheekybastard: Does this `ng-click` suggestion work for you? I did `<tab-heading ng-click="switchTab($index)">'` and use `$state.go()` in `switchTab()`, but I still need to click on the actual text to get a transition to the other tab.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out: You need to add a `select="followLink()"` method on the `<tab>` tag which gets called when the user selects the tab. `ng-click` doesn't work.

Comment: I do not understand why this is the solution? @Maui Doug solution is more complete. And even that solution is not correct or has a drawback. Why has the left state no URL except => http://run.plnkr.co/Y8IFKQ55y0LgDpuC/#!/ it should actually be => http://run.plnkr.co/Y8IFKQ55y0LgDpuC/#!/left

Comment: Because the copypasta was a few months late, compare dates. Anyways, thanks for making me aware of the issue, I've updated the answer/demo.

Answer (score 3):

Setting the tab-heading enables the links, but if you click in the tab but outside the link, the link will not activiate.  Here is the response I got from ui-router.  Thanks to Chris T.

[ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/979#issuecomment-38608681)

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/hZ6YydJRqVit3JfBfAFe?p=info)

```
    <tabset>
    <tab ui-sref="user.list">
        <tab-heading><a ui-sref-active="active">Users</a></tab-heading>
    </tab> 
    </tabset>
```

Update:

I was having issues deep liking with this, due to ui-sref-active.  As of ui-router.2.10.2.11/angular-ui-router.js this was enhanced to support inheritance - see [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219315/angular-ui-router-ui-sref-active-and-nested-states) post and [ui-router issue 18](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/818)

Comment: This should be turned into a self-answered question on StackOverflow. It is a crucial example for ui-router beginners/intermediate users on how to set states.js to have tabs visually separated from the tabs contents. IMHO one of the best plunkers about ui-router in conjunction with ui-bootstrap.

Comment: Just seeing it now, right after I commented above. Rule I forgot: Always read the entire page on SO before commenting.