# Angular-ui-router: ui-sref-active and nested states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using [`angular-ui-router`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/) and nested states in my application, and I also have a navigation bar. The nav bar is hand written, and uses `ui-sref-active` to highlight the current state. It is a two-level navigation bar.

Now, when I am in, say `Products / Categories` I would like both `Products` (in level 1) and `Categories` (in level 2) to be highlighted. However, using `ui-sref-active`, if I am in state `Products.Categories` then only that state is highlighted, not `Products`.

Is there some way to make `Products` highlight in that state?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Instead of this-

```
<li ui-sref-active="active">
    <a ui-sref="posts.details">Posts</a>
</li>
```

You can do this-

```
<li ng-class="{active: $state.includes('posts')}">
    <a ui-sref="posts.details">Posts</a>
</li>
```

---

Currently it doesn't work. There is a discussion going on here (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/pull/927) And, it will be added soon.

**UPDATE:**

For this to work, `$state` should be available in view.

```
angular.module('xyz').controller('AbcController', ['$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state) {
   $scope.$state = $state;
}]);
```

[More Info](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/704)

**UPDATE [2]:**

As of version `0.2.11`, it works out of the box. Please check the related issue: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/818

Comment: Did you make `$state` specifically available in the scope, like this `$rootScope.$state = $state`?

Comment: @jvannistelrooy Yes. Usually I don't put anything in `$rootScope` but this one is an exception.

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer. Worked perfectly for my usage. I ended up just mapping the include method on my controller's scope (`$scope.includes = $state.includes`) rather than attach the entire `$state`.

Answer (score 33):

Here's an option for when you are nesting multiple states that are not hierarchically related and you don't have a controller available for the view. You can use the UI-Router filter includedByState to check your current state against any number of named states.

```
<a ui-sref="production.products" ng-class="{active: ('production.products' | 
includedByState) || ('planning.products' | includedByState) || 
('production.categories' | includedByState) || 
('planning.categories' | includedByState)}">
  Items
</a>
```

TL;DR: Multiple, unrelated, named states need to apply an active class on the same link and you have no controller? Use [includedByState](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.filter:includedByState).

Comment: Best solution if you are creating menu-links that don't follow hierarchy of `State`. Also if you are creating a parent menu-item in menu-link and don't want to create another `State` just for the sake of using `ui-sref-active` feature. I believe `State` are meant for laying out HTML not for use in menu-links.

Comment: Also works in 1.0.0-beta.1, useful for those menu links as stated above. i had a sidebar that ui-refs to one of 4 child states of a parent abstract state. Naming the abstract state name part only, works as expected when switching between the 4 sibling states.

Comment: You could place all this logic in a function :)

Answer (score 18):

This is the solution:

```
<li class="myNonActiveStyle" ui-sref-active="myActiveStyle">
     <a ui-sref="project.details">Details</a>
</li>
```

**Edit:**

The above only works for the exact route path and will not apply the activeStyle to the nested routes. This solution should work for this:

```
<a data-ui-sref="root.parent" data-ng-class="{ active: $state.includes('root.parent') }">Link</a>
```

Comment: i have four links on which i want to add active class when one of them is selcted what i have to do for that.@holland

Comment: Or you could try just adding `data-ng-class="{ active: $state.includes('root.parent') ` to each of the links? Where `active` is the class name.

Comment: Saved my time.. Thank you

Answer (score 11):

Lets say the url tree is as follow:

`app (for home page) -> app.products -> app.products.category`

the usage:

```
<li ui-sref-active="active">
    <a ui-sref="app.products">Products</a>
</li>
```

Now, when you press on the `products`: only the products will be active.

if you press on `category`: both products and category will be active.

if you want only the category to be active if you press it, you should use: `ui-sref-active-eq` on the products, which mean that only it will be active and not it's childs.

the proper use in app.js:

```
angular.module('confusionApp', ['ui.router'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider

            // route for the home page
            .state('app', {
                url:'/',
                views: { ... }
            })

            // route for the aboutus page
            .state('app.products', {
                url:'products',
                views: { ... }
            })

            // route for the contactus page
            .state('app.products.category', {
                url:'category',
                views: { ... }
            })

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    });
```

Comment: Should be marked as right answer! Thank you, `ui-sref-active-eq` works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

So Simple,
Step 1: Add a Controller for your nav bar orin your existing controller where nav bar is included add the following

```
app.controller('navCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
        $scope.isActive = function(destination) {
        return destination === $location.path();
    }

}]);
```

Step2: In your nav bar

```
<li ng-class="{active: isActive('/home')}"><a ui-sref="app.home">Browse Journal</a></li>
```

Thats it.

Answer (score 1):

My code navigated from /productGroups to /productPartitions, which is the only way to access "productPartitions" view.

So I added a hidden anchor with ui-sref also set to "productPartitions" within the same list item that has ui-sref-active

```
<li ui-sref-active="active">
     <a ui-sref="productGroups">
     <i class="fa fa-magic"></i> Product groups </a>
     <a ui-sref="productPartitions" style="display:none;"></a>
</li>
```

Now the productGroups navigation button remains active when accessing either view

Answer (score 0):

**UI router**. Code snippet to make your navigation bar active.

**HTML**

```
<li ui-sref-active="is-active" ui-nested><a ui-sref="course">Courses</a>
</li> <li ui-sref-active="is-active" ui-nested><a ui-sref="blog">blog</a></li>
```

**CSS**

```
is-active{
      background-color: rgb(28,153,218);
}
```

**Inside courseView.HTML**

```
<button type="button" ui-sref="blog" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
```

This button is present inside course View which navigate you to next View i.e blog. and makes your navigation bar highlighted.

find similar example, a demo angular ui-router app: *https://github.com/vineetsagar7/Angualr-UI-Router*

Answer (score 0):

Here what I did to achieve the same.
Parent state is "app.message" and do not declare as abstract.

Children states are "app.message.draft", "app.message.all", "app.message.sent".

My Nav Link -

```
<a ui-sref-active="active-menu" ui-sref="app.message">Messages</a>
```

Define your children routes/links.

and update in config-

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
                if (toState.name === 'app.message') {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $state.go('app.message.draft');
                    return;
                }
            });
```