# change background and color of li using ui-sref-active

Tags: angularjs, list

I want to change the *background-color* and *color* of the **li** element when it is **active**. Below is my html page and there are links in the html page which are bind to the states in js file.. How can i change the color of span and whole background of **li** using **ui-sref-active**

```js
.state ('home', {
            url: "/home",
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl:"app/templates/home.html",
            controller: "WallCtrl"
      })
      .state('home.updates', {
          url: "/updates",
          views: {
              'menuContent': {
                  templateUrl: "app/templates/updates.html"
                 
              }
          }
      })

      .state('home.discover', {
          url: "/discover",
          views: {
              'menuContent':{
                  templateUrl: "app/templates/discover.html",
                  controller: "DiscoverCtrl"
              }
          }
      })


 .state('MyFollowList',{
          url:'/myfollowlist',
          templateUrl:'app/templates/myfollow.html',
          controller: 'MyFollowCtrl',
          resolve: {
              product_list: function ($http, ApiService, $log) {
                  $log.log("url entered :"+ url)
                  var result = $http.get(url+ ApiService.get_url('get_list')).success(function (data) {
                      $log.log("data resolved: "+ JSON.stringify(data))
                      return data;
                  }).error(function (err) {
                      $log.log(err)
                      return err;
                  });
                return result;
              }
          }
      })
```

```css
.activeClass{
    background:rgb(251,251,251);;
    color:rgb(217,52,7);
}
```

```html
<div class="lists">
     <ul list-style-type="none" class="user_Lists">
       <li class="item" menu-close  ui-sref-active="activeClass"><a ui-sref="home.updates">            <div class="HomeiconImg"></div><span>Home</span> </a></li>
       <li class="item" menu-close ui-sref-active="activeClass"><a ui-sref="home.discover">            <div class="DiscovericonImg"></div><span> Discover</span></a></li>
       <li class="item" menu-close ui-sref-active="activeClass"><a ui-sref="#">
           <div class="ActivityiconImg"></div> <span>My Activity</span></a></li>
       <li class="item"menu-close  ui-sref-active="activeClass" ><a ui-sref="MyFollowList">            <div class="FollowiconImg"></div><span>My Follow List </span></a></li>
       <hr>
       <li class="item" menu-close><a href="#">Invite Friends</a></li>
       <li class="item"menu-close><a href="#">Mock Search</a></li>
       <li class="item" menu-close><a href="#">Logout </a></li>
                   </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to this. But while doing R&d got this
Please have a look in this, there is a discussion related to this.

[Angular-ui-router: ui-sref-active and nested states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219315/angular-ui-router-ui-sref-active-and-nested-states)

Hopefully it could be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is already opened issue for this on github [Issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1431) that it is not working with abstract and child states.

For alternative solution you can check .

Stackoverflow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22273165/1632286).

It uses a way to comeout from problem

In view:-

```
ng-class="{activeClass: $state.includes('posts')}"
```

In controller:-

```
$scope.$state = $state;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the class dynamically, and add your styles, with the help of hasClass - complete reference
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element