# angularjs activate class on the menu in a sub page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a menu of nageção that works perfectly the class when clicking the option corespondente. Inside this page that opens when clicking on the menu there is a button that leads to another page, after clicking the menu loses the active class. How do I indicate that I'm still in that session.

First page working .. but clicking the button ..
[image: /]
the menu does not remain active
[image]
**HTML**

```
<li ng-class="{active: 'home.produtos'}">
        <a href="">
          <i class="fa fa-fa-briefcase"></i>
          <span class="nav-label">Produtos</span>
          <span class="fa arrow"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse" ng-class="{in: $state.includes('home.produtos','home.etiquetas','home.etiquetasview')}">
          <li>
            <a ui-sref="home.produtos">Produto</a>
          </li>
          <li ui-sref-active-eq="active">          
            <a ui-sref="home.etiquetas">Etiqueta</a>
          </li>           
        </ul>
      </li>
```

**Button in page**

```
<a  ui-sref-active-eq="active" ui-sref="home.etiquetasview({id:{{item.codigo}}})" class="btn btn-white btn-sm">
  <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View 
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a  ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="home.etiquetasview({id:{{item.codigo}}})" class="btn btn-white btn-sm">
  <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View 
</a>
```

May be this Can Help You [Angular-ui-router: ui-sref-active and nested states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219315/angular-ui-router-ui-sref-active-and-nested-states)