# Can not render a child view outside the of the parent`s parent view with ui router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have created a plunker repro here: http://plnkr.co/edit/zU3PtJamS61Ac0bAKToD?p=preview

When you go to the projects tab and click the Edit button I would expect that the Edit.Html view is rendered in the ui-view "outer".

When I debug then even the ProjectsEditController is created but the state is not really activated and the ui sticks to the projects view.

What do I wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
     <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.3/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.12.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <script src="AdministrationController.js"></script>
        <script src="ProjectsController.js"></script>
        <script src="ProjectsEditController.js"></script>
        <script src="SettingsController.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body ng-app="routedTabs" >
        <div class="wrapper">
           <div ui-view="outer">
              <header class="aside">thats the header </header>
              <div ui-view="menu" id="menu" class="aside">this is the menu aside</div>
              <div ui-view="content" class="main container">
                 <h1>Working on it... </h1>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </body>
  </html>
```

**Edit.html**

```
<div ng-bind="title"></div>
<button ui-sref="main.projects.edit({id: 10})" class="btn btn-default primary">Edit</button>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("routedTabs", ["ui.router", "ui.bootstrap"]);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("");

    $stateProvider
        .state("main", {
            abtract: true,
            url: "",
            views: {

                'content@': {
                    templateUrl: 'administration.html',
                    controller: 'AdministrationController'
                }
            }
        })
        .state("main.projects", {
            url: "/projects",
            views: {
                'menu@': {
                    template: 'test'
                },
                'planner@main': {
                    templateUrl: 'projects.html',
                    controller: 'ProjectsController'
                }
            }
        }).state('main.projects.edit', {
            url: '/edit/:id',
            views: {
                'outer@': {
                    templateUrl: 'edit.html',
                    controller: 'ProjectsEditController'
                }
            }
        })
        .state("main.tab2", {
            url: "/settings",
            views: {
                'menu@': {
                    template: 'bla'
                },
                'planner@main': {
                    templateUrl: 'settings.html',
                    controller: 'SettingsController'
                }
            }
        });

});
```

**UPDATE**

According to @Karthik`s statement I can not render the edit view into the "outer" ui-view.

I have prepared here a plunker without abstract main state and tabs. In this sample is just a projects view with an edit project button which should render the edit view into the ui-view called "outer" and indeeded it works!

http://plnkr.co/edit/ogQIpfHz7Cy9Jo03czKL?p=preview

So my new question is, what is the difference between those samples that it works in this plunker but not in the tabs plunker?

And how can I concretely make it work with tabs then?

Comment: I dont think you will be able to render a nested state into the main view. You may have to look at rearranging the states.

Comment: I have done this before. But since I added the abstract main state with the tabs the edit.html is not rendered anymore into the outer... Ui-view. I will prepare tomorrow another plunker to prove exactly this.

Comment: @Karthik As I promised I have updated my question with new information + a new plunker please read it to understand more :-)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Yea it works. But my point was why to complicate the state structure with nesting when there is no need for it. Rendering the nested state in to a main view will have no benefit in accessing its parents scope or its resolved dependencies. I would prefer having a main level state "edit:id" to keep it simple. Anyways, I will try to play with your plnkr to see what is stopping you rendering nested state.

Comment: Okay. The issue seem to be the state hierarchy. It trys to find the view with in the same state or its anchestor states. The top most view it could find is "content" which is the root view for you. Since "outer" view is on even top of the root, its unable render the template. My suggestion to you would be either to have the state name changed to root level or have it rendered to root view which is "content" in your case

Comment: Still... My question is why does it work in the second plunker? The outer ui view is at the same place.

Comment: Apparently you can render it in the outer@ only if the `<div ui-view="outer"></div>` doesn't contain any other ui-views, check http://plnkr.co/edit/ogQIpfHz7Cy9Jo03czKL?p=preview

Comment: @teleaziz your plunker does not work when I press the edit button. I did what you said but your statement is not true. I edited the plunker see: http://plnkr.co/edit/4pAEXfcSO5Su535r3NoG?p=preview

Comment: I know I could rearrange the states/html layout with the ui-views and consider from the start that I will have fullscreen views but this I will do only where there is no better solution because still the question is open why does it work in the second plunker where the outer ui view is also outside the root state which targets the content ui view inside the outer ui-view.

Comment: @Elisa , sorry forgot to save, check this one , http://plnkr.co/edit/WE8O3b3anwaZCXYG9ndd?p=preview

Comment: @teleaziz This is what I thought and why the outer ui-view must enclose all other layout. Yes your sample works... but the rest of the layout is visible too because it is not replaced it is inserted. I need a full replace :-)

Comment: @teleaziz,@Elisa,@Karthik, I think the solution mentioned by Mior in answer is perfect.It's the issue with the go function and nothing to do with the insertion/replace of child to main ui-view.

Answer (score 1):

Your projects is working and edit tab is displayed (if you debug your js code you will see it). In your case problem is in your `AdministrationController.js`.

On every `update` event form `tabset` is called `go` function with route `/projects` (current tab)

```
$scope.go = function(route){
    $state.go(route);
};
```

This changes state back to `main.projects` so it seems like state was not changes which it actually was.

You probably want to re-write triggering within `AdministrationController.js` or found out why is `update`/`go` function triggered when leaving tab.

See if answer in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891335/angular-ui-bootstrap-tabs-not-rendering-ui-view) helps. You could use this approach instead of `update` function.

As temporary solution could be used something like:

```
$scope.go = function(route){
    if($state.$current.name != 'main.projects.edit'){
        $state.go(route);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the issue identification, I have tried the same thing in plunker and it have resolved the issue with edit controller. The answer should be accepted and mark as complete